# Add list of dictionaries from AJAX response to datatable

Tags: python, jquery, json, ajax, flask

I'm trying to refresh a DataTable using a list of dictionaries received as AJAX response, but the table gets cleared and no data gets added. No errors in the network log, and successfully receiving a response.

This is just as mentioned in https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()

**Flask:**

```
    c_data = []
    for c in myData:
        c_data.append({
            'name': c[0],
            'branch': c[1],
            'city': c[2],
            'state': c[3],
            'country': c[4],
            'pin': c[5],
            'landmark': c[6],
            })
 
    return json.dumps(c_data)
```

**JQuery:**

```
function makeRequest() {
var pageNum = table.hasOwnProperty('page') ? table.page.info().page : 1;
 if (pageNum > 0) {
        $.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify({ "pageNum": pageNum }),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/my/url",
        success: function(data){
                console.log(jQuery.type(data);
                console.log(data);
                table.clear();
                table.rows.add(data);
                table.draw();
                }
        })

}
```

**Response in Network log:**

> type- array data- [{"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "Tokyo",
> "state": "P3", "country": "Japan", "pin": "110011", "landmark":
> "L1"},{"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "Tokyo", "state":
> "P3", "country": "Japan", "pin": "110011", "landmark":
> "L2"},...{"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "Tokyo", "state":
> "P3", "country": "Japan", "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L30"}]

Can you please suggest how I can map the data using table.rows.add ?

Comment: You are appending to ```c_data``` but are returning ```err_data``` which is an entirely different variable (at least from your posted code)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I'm using c_data. Updated the same in my question.

Comment: The data must be an array. See https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/18660/ajaxsource-json-dictionary. You can add a `callback` to turn the data into an array.  See https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.